# ROS Melodic Installation Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) in VirtualBox: "gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data"

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, ros

When I execute the line `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654` as well as the subsitute according to http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu it gives an error saying: `gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: Any change in the code has no effect. You need to run your code again until it works (or you add more download locations to go through in an if-statement so that the chance is less that you do not catch a download); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62353595/11154841).**

I just leave the following old part as a proof that any placebo code changes did not help me, it was random and it strangely appeared at every first run, while at the second, it usually worked.

---

I had a similar thing, installing ROS Melodic, though in my case with Docker on WSL2.

I got  `=> ERROR [stage-1  2/11] RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources  3.5s` ... `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Cannot assign requested address`:

```
#5 0.602 Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.CWiWk2Kd63/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
#5 2.350 gpg: keyserver receive failed: Cannot assign requested address
```

I had to run it another time, and it somehow seemed to run through - I thought at first. This was the code:

```
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list' &&\
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

But then I got a new error:

```
#5 353.2 Get:1306 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 usb-modeswitch amd64 2.5.2+repack0-2ubuntu1 [53.6 kB]
#5 353.3 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/opencv/libopencv-core3.2_3.2.0+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#5 353.3    Hashes of expected file:
#5 353.3     - SHA512:6c5ee067a73d330eeea4ba0426f1f41a3021e1d91548ab7530706ba3d80b25df330bb37be2e753e1c87fbcd5d50f57c2e2de80ee91c59a80b69a8a6cc982bef5
#5 353.3     - SHA256:292740f9146eca5728a32cdf40a27efae4a724f76cf40601b8ef57368cde5bd5
#5 353.3     - SHA1:3a27b6ade543bd5f2ca5087ed3bf57b3df569d89 [weak]
#5 353.3     - MD5Sum:a629fdd926ae5e75fc878403a5409c1a [weak]
#5 353.3     - Filesize:708876 [weak]
#5 353.3    Hashes of received file:
#5 353.3     - SHA512:0fd63abb591a56fb4f0b790483b53df60037e2494a26913430cd5fb70ed21e05d3f0cc355562ce354f9ee07b9caf8d23a9d56d281e384ba973403dfd02a73cd4
#5 353.3     - SHA256:dcf88559ae189cde343f2be1e228d889ffa40746e0dcd9330600243606bbe949
#5 353.3     - SHA1:e5c14569a3bbfdb2e93f08535147e3547379c418 [weak]
#5 353.3     - MD5Sum:2d778738711f7745937060a2b50ba051 [weak]
#5 353.3     - Filesize:708876 [weak]
#5 353.3    Last modification reported: Wed, 26 Sep 2018 13:48:22 +0000
#5 353.3 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
#5 353.3 Fetched 556 MB in 5min 31s (1680 kB/s)
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -c sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list' &&    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654 &&   apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y ros-melodic-desktop-full]: exit code: 100
```

I am not sure which code line caused that error. If it is caused by `apt-get install -y ros-melodic-desktop-full`, then it is beyond this question. I have solved that issue later. But if that error is caused by the first two lines, it is relevant enough to post it here.

Afterwards, the `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Cannot assign requested address` error appeared again.

Finally, it seemed to help adding more `RUN`'s. And I post the other code lines that go beyond this question just to show the aim of it all: installing ros-melodic and python-catkin-tools.

```
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y ros-melodic-desktop-full
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y python-catkin-tools
```