# ROS Melodic source install problem in Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) in Virtual Box

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, ros

Since the normal install failed for me ([ROS Melodic Installation problem in Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239011/ros-melodic-installation-problem-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionicin-virtualbox)) I tried the source installation according to http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source and tried the first step after setting up sources.list with 
`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'` which was 
`sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build-essential`. 
However i ran into a problem stating `E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`. This was followed by `apt-get update` which resulted in :

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

and when i ran `--fix-missing` it said `--fix-missing: command not found`. I have lost hope in installing ROS. I do not know if this problem is due to virtual box as my friend who boots ubuntu from a disk followed the same site as me and faced no issued.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the exact issue might be but here is something to get you up and running with ROS.

You can download an image for VirtualBox of ubuntu with ROS preinstalled from [here](https://downloads.ubiquityrobotics.com/vm.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have not yet been able to try it but thanks for your time, I will certainly try it!